# Direct link to main folder directory

Tags: php

I am starting my own project which can help me to organize and manage my knowledge, used solutions, good code snippets etc. For example I have that sections:

- HTML

  - MARKUP
  - API (actual)
  - API (future)
- CSS

  - IE9+
  - IE Legacy
  - New
- JS

  - JSON
  - AJAX
  - ES5
  - ES6

Etc..
Probably there will be many subfolders in main project folder and each of them can has another subfolder. In the main project folder I will have a style.css for styling entire project. And each snippet should be styled by this css file. It will be complicated to set style.css localication in each file like: '../../' or '../'based on subfolders structure because when I move something to another folder it won't work.
Is there any way to set one style.css localization in each file, which is file moving proof and don't use direct link with domain name?
I mean something like $mainFolderDirectory which can implement on each file

Answer (score 0):

You can access the css folder from the root folder using '/css/file.css' e.g

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/file.css" />
```

You can also do the same with images etc. This will allow you to access these common folders from any sub folder in your app.